# Finding clusters of line segments in a list

Tags: python, algorithm, math

I have a list of line segments represented as `x` and `y` coordinates and I'm trying to find groups of lines such that all angles within the group are within 20 degrees. But my problem is that `math.degrees(math.atan2(-0.1,-1))` (=-174.29) and `math.degrees(math.atan2(0.1,-1))` (=174.29) should make two points in the same group, but the difference in face value is greater than 20. I wonder if my code should do what I want and avoids the 180/-180 problem:

```
import math

endpoints = [((2, 11), (2, 8)), ((11, 3), (2, 5)), ((13, 7), (9, 12)), ((5, 5), (15, 12)), ((15, 4), (8, 1)), ((15, 14), (14, 3)), ((2, 4), (6, 5)), ((1, 13), (13, 11)), ((8, 11), (12, 15)), ((12, 4), (7, 1))]

def find_angle(p1,p2):
    x1 = p1[0]
    y1 = p1[1]
    x2 = p2[0]
    y2 = p2[1]

    dx = max(x2-x1,x1-x2)
    if dx == x2-x1:
        dy = y2-y1
    else:
        dy = y1-y2

    return math.degrees(math.atan2(dy,dx))

endpointsbyangle = sorted([(find_angle(p1,p2), (p1,p2)) for p1, p2 in endpoints], key=lambda x: x[0])

prev = -190
group = []
allgroups = []
for (theta, (p1, p2)) in endpointsbyangle:
    if prev == -190:
        group.append((p1,p2))
        prev = theta
    else:
        if abs(prev - theta) < 20:
            group.append((p1,p2))
        else:
            allgroups.append(group)
            group = [(p1,p2)]
            prev = theta

print dict(enumerate(allgroups))
```

Any thought appreciated.

Comment: For each group of lines, such as `(2, 11), (2, 8)`, or `(11, 3), (2, 5)`, you want to know which ones have a 20 degrees angle inbetween ?

Comment: @IMCoins I want to make groups of lines so that there's a maximum 20 degree angle difference between them all.

Comment: I am confused, you want to seek the angle between lines, but you have a function that takes as input `(p1, p2)`, meaning 2 points. Considering a segment line is made of 2 points, you should have a function that takes either 2 lines as input, or 4 points. Correct me if I'm wrong please.

Comment: @IMCoins `endpointsbyangle` should be a list of `(angle, (endpoint1, endpoint2))` tuple sorted by `angle`. The last loop is where the comparison of angles take place.

Comment: Maybe this help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1269050/finding-the-angle-between-two-line-equations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to replace your line

```
if abs(prev - theta) < 20:
```

with

```
if abs(prev - theta) < 20 or abs(prev - theta) > 340:
```

This then captures the situations where the calculated angle is near 360 degrees.

However, if I understand you, you have another problem. If the angle ABC is exactly 5 degrees (for example), and angle CAB is also 5 degrees, then angle ACB is 170 degrees and would fail your test. In other words, it is not possible for "all angles within the group are within 20 degrees" for a group of 3 points. You should also allow an angle to be within 20 degrees of 180 degrees. So perhaps you should use the line

```
if (abs(prev - theta) < 20
   or abs(prev - theta) > 340
   or abs(prev - theta - 180) < 20):
```

That depends on exactly what you mean by your requirement "all angles within the group are within 20 degrees."

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm actually calculating the angle of each line segment w.r.t. the horizontal axis, which is why I'm using `math.atan2`. The angles of the lines in a group should be within a 20-degree difference. I guess another way to put it is, I'm trying to group lines with a similar slope together.

Comment: Do you think it's actually necessary to select `dx = max(x2-x1,x1-x2)`? Could `dx = x2-x1` do?